# How is it possible that geopandas and sf give different summary statistics output for the same file?

Tags: python, r, shapefile, geopandas, r-sf

I am using [this shapefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L7eOBIVMSvCxF2-KNeF2oikURlvTCHUX/view?usp=sharing) with polygons containing a variable `z`.

According to the `sf` package in `R`, the maximum value of the `z`-column is 43, according to `geopandas` in `Python` the maximum value of the `z`-column is 7.

How on earth is this possible?

in `R`:

```r
library(sf)
theshapefile <- read_sf("z_mystery.shp")
summary(theshapefile$z)
```

```
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-50.00  -34.00  -17.50  -16.91   -1.50   43.00
```

in `Python`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
theshapefile = gpd.read_file("z_mystery.shp")
print(theshapefile.z.describe())
```

```
count    78250.000000
mean       -21.110454
std         16.849647
min        -50.000000
25%        -35.500000
50%        -21.000000
75%         -6.500000
max         11.500000
Name: z, dtype: float64
```

Comment: When trying the python3 path, I see `pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:28992: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: no database context specified)`, any idea how to solve that? Versions are up to date, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same results from both `sf` and `geopandas`.

In python (I am using 3.9.6 and geopandas version as 0.9.0).

```
import geopandas as gpd
x = gpd.read_file('z_mystery.shp')
print(x['z'].describe())
```

This outputs:

```
count    200687.000000
mean        -16.910993
std          20.111462
min         -50.000000
25%         -34.000000
50%         -17.500000
75%          -1.500000
max          43.000000
Name: z, dtype: float64
```